# I get error when i run project and call any action from the controller

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

when I select a list of data from database i get error
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Bookstore.Models.Repositories.BookDbRepository.List() in BookDbRepository.cs, line 38

```
BookController 

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Bookstore.Models.Repositories;
using Bookstore.Models;
using Bookstore.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace Bookstore.Controllers
{
    public class BookController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBookstorerRepository<Book> bookRepository;
        private readonly IBookstorerRepository<Author> authorRepository;
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment hosting;
        public BookController(IBookstorerRepository<Book> bookRepository, IBookstorerRepository<Author> authorRepository,IHostingEnvironment hosting)
        {
            this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
            this.authorRepository = authorRep

ository;
            this.hosting = hosting;
        }

        // GET: BookController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var book = bookRepository.List();
            return View(book);
        }

        // GET: BookController/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var book = bookRepository.Find(id);
            return View(book);
        }

        // GET: BookController/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            
            return View(GetallAuthors());
        }

        // POST: BookController/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(BookAuthor model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    string FileName = string.Empty;
                    if(model.file != null)
                    { 
                        string uploads = Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath,"uploads");
                        FileName = model.file.FileName;
                        string FullPath = Path.Combine(uploads, FileName);
                        model.file.CopyTo(new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.Create));
                    }

                    if (model.AuthorId == -1)
                    {
                        ViewBag.message = "please select an author";
                        return View(GetallAuthors());
                    }
                    var author = authorRepository.Find(model.AuthorId);
                    Book book = new Book
                    {
                        Id = model.BookId,
                        Title = model.Title,
                        Description = model.Description,
                        ImageUrl = FileName,
                        Author = author
                    };
                    bookRepository.Add(book);

                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "you hav to fill all required data");
            return View(GetallAuthors());
        }

        // GET: BookController/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var book = bookRepository.Find(id);
            var authorId = book.Author == null ? book.Author.Id = 0 : book.Author.Id;
            var viewmodel = new BookAuthor()
            {
                BookId=book.Id,
                Title=book.Title,
                Description=book.Description,
                AuthorId= authorId,
                Authors=authorRepository.List().ToList(),
                ImageUrl=book.ImageUrl
                
            };

            return View(viewmodel);
        }

        // POST: BookController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, BookAuthor viewmodel)
        {
            try
            {
                string FileName = string.Empty;
                if (viewmodel.file != null)
                {
                    string uploads = Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath, "uploads");
                    FileName = viewmodel.file.FileName;
                    string FullPath = Path.Combine(uploads, FileName);
                    

                    //delete old file
                    string oldfilename = bookRepository.Find(viewmodel.BookId).ImageUrl;
                    string fulloldpath = Path.Combine(uploads, oldfilename);

                    if(FullPath != fulloldpath)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fulloldpath);

                        //save new file
                        viewmodel.file.CopyTo(new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.Create));
                    }
                }


                var author = authorRepository.Find(viewmodel.AuthorId);
                Book book = new Book
                {
                    
                    Title = viewmodel.Title,
                    Description = viewmodel.Description,
                    Author = author,
                    ImageUrl = FileName
                    

                };
                bookRepository.Update(viewmodel.BookId,book);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: BookController/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var book = bookRepository.Find(id);
            return View(book);
        }

        // POST: BookController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ConfirmDelete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                bookRepository.Delete(id);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }



        List<Author> fillselectlist()
        {
            var Authors = authorRepository.List().ToList();
            Authors.Insert(0, new Author { Id = -1, fullname = "... please select item ..." });
            return Authors;
        }

        BookAuthor GetallAuthors()
        {
            var viewmodel = new BookAuthor
            {
                Authors = fillselectlist()
            };
            return viewmodel;
        }

    }
}
```

```
Book class


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bookstore.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
       public Author Author { get; set; }

    }
}
```

```
BookDbRepository 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Bookstore.Models.Repositories
{
    public class BookDbRepository : IBookstorerRepository<Book>
    {
        BookstoreDbContext db;
        public BookDbRepository(BookstoreDbContext _db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public void Add(Book entity)
        {
           
           db.Books.Add(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var book = Find(id);
            db.Books.Remove(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public Book Find(int id)
        {
            var book = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
            return book;
        }

        public IList<Book> List()
        {
            return db.Books.Include(a=>a.Author).ToList();
        }

        public void Update(int id, Book newbook)
        {
            db.Books.Update(newbook);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

```
Startup 

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Bookstore.Models.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Bookstore.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Bookstore
{
    public class Startup 
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddScoped<IBookstorerRepository<Author>, AuthorDbRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IBookstorerRepository<Book>, BookDbRepository>();
            services.AddDbContext<BookstoreDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlCon"));
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

                
           
        }
    }
}



    }
}
```

I get this error
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Bookstore.Models.Repositories.BookDbRepository.List() in BookDbRepository.cs, line 38

Comment: As per your description,  This code ` return db.Books.Include(a=>a.Author).ToList();` within your `IList<Book> List()` method under `BookDbRepository`  producing the error, make sure, all author has the book or it allows null value.  You could set null to `public Author? Author` as you are adding author as well within your `book list page` here `db.Books.Include(a=>a.Author).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

> I get this error An unhandled exception occurred while processing the
> request. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.
> Bookstore.Models.Repositories.BookDbRepository.List() in
> BookDbRepository.cs, line 38

Well, the error you are getting may have two maain reason.

**Reason:1**

Either of your data in `Book` or `Author` table is empty.

**Reason:2**

You want to allow empty data row for `author table` in views. which causing the error.

**Solution:**

If you want to handle `empty result set` or `null data` in controler you can modify your code as below:

```cs
public class BookStorerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBookstorerRepository _bookRepository;

        public BookStorerController(IBookstorerRepository bookRepository)
        {
            _bookRepository = bookRepository;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var booklist = _bookRepository.List();
            if (booklist.Count == 0 || booklist == null)
            {
                return Content("No data found!");
            }
            return View(booklist);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This condition `booklist.Count == 0 || booklist == null` will save your program to break while throw exception.

**Solution: 2**

You even cam handle the "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in your class as well. In that case modidy the class as below:

```cs
public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
   
        public   Author? Author { get; set; }
    }
```

**Solution: View**

If you can handle `null/empty` row in view you can do as below as well.

```cs
@item.Author?.Name
```

Or full view should be as following:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Book>


<table class="table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Id
            <th>Title
            <th>Description
            <th>Author Name
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Title</td>
                <td>@item.Description</td>
                <td>@item.Author?.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Output:**

[image]